# md5sum messing up with filenames with spaces

Tags: linux, md5

I'm trying to generate a md5 for each file that has no user.comment extended attribute and then parse that md5 in the file's extended attribute.
My script works fine but only for filenames that have no spaces in them.

```
cd /tank/test
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.txt
do
  if [[ -n $(getfattr -n user.comment "$f") ]]; then
    continue
  else
    md5=($(md5sum $f))
    setfattr -n user.comment -v "$md5" "$f"
  fi
done
```

I saw a lot people using the `find` command instead, but I don't know how to make it work for my case.

Comment: Does it help to add "" around the $f? Like in `md5sum "$f"`

Comment: Holy! You the man lol
Can't believe I missed that, thanks a lot :)

Comment: ;) Keep up scripting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is, [as pointed out by @wigy](https://superuser.com/questions/916152/md5sum-messing-up-with-filenames-with-spaces#comment1233523_916152), that you're not quoting your variable. This means that a file name with whitespace will be treated as separate files. The general rule of thumb is that you should *always* quote your variables unless you have a very good reason not to.

That said, here's a simplified version of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
for f in /tank/test/*txt
do
    [[ -n $(getfattr -n user.comment "$f" 2>/dev/null) ]] ||
        setfattr -n user.comment -v "$(md5sum "$f")" "$f"
done
```

Using shell globs, as you did, is generally simpler and cleaner but here's how to do it with `find`:

```
find /tank/test/ -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 |
 while IFS= read -r -d '' f
 do
     [[ -n $(getfattr -n user.comment "$f" 2>/dev/null) ]] ||
         setfattr -n user.comment -v "$(md5sum "$f")" "$f"
 done
```